# Arithmetic picard rank of smooth cubic surfaces

Tags: algebraic-geometry, arithmetic, surfaces

Assume a smooth cubic surface is defined over a field $k$ characteristic $0$, that it has line defined over $k$ and that its arithmetic Picard rank over $k$ is maximal i.e. $7$. Does this imply that the surface has to contain a second line defined over $k$ which does not meet the first ?